# How can I set state in a child component from a parent?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a slider component nested in a form in my app. The slider adjusts parameters that live in a `Redux store`.

Normally, the slider would be controlled, its values set by the props passed down from the `Redux store`. When the slider is moved, `onChange` would dispatch an action to update the `store`, and the slider values would change.

However, in this case, this solution poses problems:

1. The slider has 100+ steps, so dragging it 50% across means dozens
   and dozens of `onChange` events
2. Since the slider itself isn't connected to the `store`, every `onChange` forces a re-render on the parent, as `props` are changing. This eviscerates performance.

So, I've implemented a partial solution:

1. the slider values live in the slider's state, so dragging it just re-renders the slider with `onChange` events.
2. an `afterChange` event--which fires when the user releases the mouse after dragging the slider, `dispatch`es the new values to the `store`.

However, the parent has a "reset" button that should set the slider's values to their initial state.

So, how can I communicate to the slider component from the parent that it's time to reset values?

Comment: why not simply debounce the `onChange`?

Comment: i haven't worked w/ debouncing before (just had to Google it, in fact), but wouldn't it negatively impact ux? eg user drags slider, but since it's debounced, it doesn't update right away & appears to lag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your parent's reset button do whatever it needs to do to update the store.
When store changes, the updated value will be used as new props.

You can then define the reset logic with `componentWillReceiveProps` on your Slider component

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: i think this is the best approach. Initially I had it in my head that setting state directly from props was an anti-pattern, but after reading your docs link & googling, [I realize that's only in](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) `getInitialState`

Comment: Appears to be working great, just wanted to follow-up for posterity: the `currentValue` of the slider is now set in `componentWillMount` to `[0, this.props.max]`, with drag events triggering state updates.  Then, I added a `isSliderDefault` switch to my `store` which gets flipped off/on during `UPDATE_SLIDER_VALS` and `CLEAR_SLIDERS` actions, respectively.  Finally, passing that prop to my slider, I do a simple check in `componentWillReceiveProps`, which resets `currentValue` to `[0, this.props.max]` if `isSliderDefault === true`